# I am having trouble implementing SFML into Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

This is the output of the attempt I have tried multiple different tutorials through today and I seem to get this same output:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::CircleShape::CircleShape(float,unsigned int)" (__imp_??0CircleShape@sf@@QAE@MI@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::CircleShape::~CircleShape(void)" (__imp_??1CircleShape@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::clear(class sf::Color const &)" (__imp_?clear@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVColor@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall sf::RenderTarget::draw(class sf::Drawable const &,class sf::RenderStates const &)" (__imp_?draw@RenderTarget@sf@@QAEXABVDrawable@2@ABVRenderStates@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(class sf::VideoMode,class sf::String const &,unsigned int,struct sf::ContextSettings const &)" (__imp_??0RenderWindow@sf@@QAE@VVideoMode@1@ABVString@1@IABUContextSettings@1@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall sf::RenderWindow::~RenderWindow(void)" (__imp_??1RenderWindow@sf@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class sf::RenderStates const sf::RenderStates::Default" (__imp_?Default@RenderStates@sf@@2V12@B) referenced in function _main
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class sf::Color const sf::Color::Green" (__imp_?Green@Color@sf@@2V12@B) referenced in function _main
1>C:\Users\mrgnh\source\repos\My SFML Game\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-graphics-d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Users\mrgnh\source\repos\My SFML Game\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-window-d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Users\mrgnh\source\repos\My SFML Game\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-system-d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Users\mrgnh\source\repos\My SFML Game\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-audio-d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Users\mrgnh\source\repos\My SFML Game\SFML-2.5.1\lib\sfml-network-d.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Users\mrgnh\source\repos\My SFML Game\Debug\My SFML Game.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 17 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "My SFML Game.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Your library is build for x64 and you are trying to compile for x86 so either build the library for x86 or aim your build for x64, also make sure you are linking the library with the compiler.

Comment: You are mixing 32 and 64 bit. If your SFML is x64 your application must be x64 as well. Same goes for 32 bit. My advice is to make sure everything is x64 / 64 bit unless you are shipping your binaries to people who have 10+ year old computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize I was compiling for x86 so I switched it to x64 thank you for that comment :)

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.